# How to fix a parameter in SolveAlways

Tags: equation-solving, parameters

In expression:

```
SolveAlways[f1(a)+f2(b)x+f3(c)x^2+f4(d)x^3==f5(d)x^2+f6(e),x]
```

Functions fi are known. How do I tell mathematica that d is a fixed constant?. I want to obtain parameters a, b, c, and e, in terms of d.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help, I thought it would be very easy but can't find a way to do it.

Comment: Try this one `Solve[! Eliminate[!f1[a] + f2[b] x + f3[c] x^2 + f4[d] x^3 == f5[d] x^2 + f6[e], x], {a, b, c, e}]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Note that mathematica does not use parentheses `()` for function application, only square brackets `[]`.

Comment: Thanks to @yarchik. Question answered with your help. I don’t know how indicate this, there is no checkmark sign in my question posted.

Comment: It is fine, I answered in a comment because it was a small thing.